# How do I create a new logic brick for blender?

Tags: blender

I am thinking of making a new logic brick to contribute or 10, but need to get a template/idea of where to start, I want to make a 6dof actuator and sensor first, that can trigger based on rotation targets or distance limits etc, and a actuator that can remove or change a 6dof target to a new position or object and position,

I am making a open source 3d puzzle game with limited ads in game, but need to make a few logic bricks, for me and the community....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no coding tutorials regarding BGE Game logic that I'm aware of, but here are some pointers for the code:

The game logic parts are mostly in:

https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/source/gameengine/GameLogic/

You'll see that sensors implement the ISensor interface. Browse through a few different sensors to see how they work. Blender has NDOF device support, so NDOF events already exist (get handled by our GHOST layer: https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_NDOFManager.h ). You could create a new manager like the mouse manager (see the gamelogic directory for the different managers ).

With this information you should be able to get started. Read the existing code carefully, you'll be able to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this commit [Mouse actuator commit](https://developer.blender.org/D559) as your template to add a new actuator.